# xCode 5.1 cannot select @2x images in storyboard for image views and buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, uistoryboard, xcode5.1

I've ran into an issue with xCode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008). For some reason, the storyboard drop downs refuse to show @2x.png images for image views and buttons. If I paste the full image name, like 06-magnify@2x.png I get a blue  not found question mark. Both regular and 2x images are added to a project and are visible in the project navigator. In the copy bundle resources I see that 2x images are copied over.

**What's causing me to be unable to select @2x images in a UIStoryboard in xCode 5.1?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, it appears that **the storyboard itself displays 1x image as placeholder** (which looks like crap), but upon building on the actual device, the @2x image is displayed instead. I expected a more WYSIWYG behavior from a storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't supposed to select them yourself. The point is that you simply set the regular image name and the app will grab the appropriate @2x image when requested on retina devices.

Comment: That's exactly the behavior I've expected, however the storyboard still picks the 1X images, when @2x are available. The result is bloated, stretched and pixelated icons :(

Comment: Can you create a sample project that shows this behavior and upload it somewhere? Hard to diagnose this without seeing it happen, because it should just work.